# Unhandled Exception Error : NoSuchMethodError : class bool has no instance Method ' [ ]'

Tags: flutter, dart

```
Future<void> fetchAndSetProducts() async {
    const url =
        'https://flutter-shop-2b595-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/products.json';
    try {
      final response = await http.get(url);

      final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;

      final List<Product> loadedProducts = [];

      extractedData.forEach((prodId, prodData) {
        loadedProducts.add(Product(
            id: prodId,
            title: prodData['title'],
            description: prodData['description'],
            price: prodData['price'],
            imageUrl: prodData['imageUrl']));
      });
      _items = loadedProducts;
      notifyListeners();

      //print(json.decode(response.body));
    } catch (error) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Could you share more code? Probably prodData is not defined as bool?

Comment: kindly share the errors

Answer (score 0):

The response of that url is:

```
{
  "-N5Pn8iWUJrxG85wpOMw": {
    "description": "an apple laptop",
    "imageUrl": "https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/uWjEogFLUTBc8mSvagdiuP-970-80.jpg",
    "isFavorite": false,
    "price": 1234,
    "title": "laptop"
  },
  "-N5Q7PtvJADT214YwUvp": {
    "description": "it is an apple laptop",
    "imageUrl": "https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/uWjEogFLUTBc8mSvagdiuP-970-80.jpg",
    "isFavorite": false,
    "price": 123,
    "title": "laptop"
  },
  "-N5Q8CzKquMt73v9DfeX": {
    "description": "an apple laptop",
    "imageUrl": "https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/uWjEogFLUTBc8mSvagdiuP-970-80.jpg",
    "isFavorite": false,
    "price": 123,
    "title": "laptop"
  },
  "isFavorite": false
}
```

Notice how the first 3 fields indeed have a map as value that can be parsed correctly. But there's a 4th called `isFavorite` that has a boolean as value.
You could add an extra check for this to prevent it, maybe like:

```
  extractedData.forEach((prodId, prodData) {
    if (prodData is Map) {
        loadedProducts.add(Product(
            id: prodId,
            title: prodData['title'],
            description: prodData['description'],
            price: prodData['price'],
            imageUrl: prodData['imageUrl']));
    }
  });
```